# Притяжательное местоимение и однородные члены с разделительным союзом

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, местоимения

1. *Клиента или заказчика в первую очередь волнуют **его/их** собственные интересы.*
2. *Клиента или клиентку в первую очередь волнуют **их/свои** собственные интересы.* (Подлежащие разного грамматического рода.)

Хотя местоимении "свои" тут не очень подходит, т. к. оно относится к производителю действия, а у нас производителем являются "интересы".

Answer (score 1):

> Клиента или заказчика в первую очередь волнуют его/их собственные интересы.

Тут нужно разобраться, чем отличается клиент то заказчика. Возможно, это синонимы, союз *или* употреблен в значении «то есть». Тогда нужно добавить запятые.

**Клиента, или заказчика, в первую очередь волнуют его собственные интересы**

В общем случае, если союз *или* имеет разделительное значение, то после слов "А или Б" в предложении употребляется единственное число.

> Клиента или клиентку в первую очередь волнуют их/свои собственные интересы.

Тут опять "А или Б", а значит требуется ед.ч. А поскольку род разный, то выход один — писать "свои".

**Клиента или клиентку в первую очередь волнуют свои собственные интересы.**

Думаю, споры о том, кто производитель действия, ничего не дают в данном случае. Если внимательно прочитать [§170. Возвратные и притяжательные местоимения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm#%D0%B7_02), то становится ясно, что возвратно-притяжательное местоимение *свой* не обязательно должно относиться к производителю действия.

> Дедушка приказал нас с сестрицей посадить за стол прямо против себя (Аксаков) производителем действия, выраженного глаголом посадить, от которого синтаксически зависит сочетание против себя, является не дедушка (дедушка приказал, а посадить должен кто-то другой), но по смыслу против себя здесь значит «против него», так как другого «претендента» на соотносительную связь с возвратным местоимением в приведенном предложении нет.)

Вопрос о производителе действия возникает лишь тогда, когда предложение становится неоднозначным.

Comment: В нашем случае "клиент" и "заказчик" — это по сути одно лицо, только может по-разному называться; но я бы не стал придумывать пояснительную конструкцию, т. к. здесь нет пояснения — просто иногда мы лицо, которому предоставляем услуги, называем клиентом, иногда заказчиком.

Comment: Понятно, тогда см. про А или Б.

Comment: "Клиента волнует конкурент своими ценами", — по-вашему, производитель действия — клиент (он волнуется), но не волнуют же его собственные цены. Разве грамматика в данном случае не важнее семантики?

Comment: *Клиента волнует свой конкурент со своими ценами*. Что скажете? Не уверен, как это теоретически обосновать, но первый "свой" относится к клиенту, а второй к конкуренту.

Comment: Интересно. Вот нашёл: "Местоимение «свой» указывает принадлежность предмета говорящему, или его собеседнику, или третьему лицу, которые являются в предложении подлежащим (https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/mestoimenie/pritiazhatelnyie-mestoimeniia.html), "Местоимение свой можно использовать лишь тогда, когда лицо, предмет, на принадлежность которому указывает местоимение, является активным производителем действия и в предложении занимает место подлежащего" (http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/morfologia/mestoimenie/prityazhatelnie-mestoimeniya-v-russkom-yazike/1271/?q=463&n=1271).

Comment: Да и не кажется ли вам, что местоимение "свой" здесь ну совсем не звучит? Хочется сказать "его конкурент".

Comment: Кстати, приведённые мной выше правила весьма спорны: "Я попросил его дать мне свой телефон". "Свой" относится не к подлежащему, а к производителю соответствующего действия. Однако один факт остаётся неизменным: везде смысловой производитель действия совпадает с грамматическим — не встречал, чтоб "свой" относился к смысловому производителю, тогда как он не совпадает с грамматическим.

Comment: Дважды "свой" не звучит, но по отдельности - да. 
Каждого клиента волнует свой конкурент с его ценами. Данного клиента волнует его конкурент со своими ценами.

Comment: Слово "каждый" многое меняет. "Клиента волнует свой конкурент" — вот здесь не звучит.

Comment: Зависит от контекста. Мой конкурент клиента не волнует — клиента волнует свой конкурент с его ценами.

Comment: У нас предложение самостоятельное, без контекста. К слову, у вас теперь получается, что конкурент использует цены нашего клиента.

Comment: Тут неоднозначность, можно понять и так и эдак. Нехорошо, конечно, но не отменяет мой главный посыл: местоимение "свой" не всегда обязано относиться к производителю действия.

Comment: Возвратное местоимение "себя" и не возвратно-притяжательное местоимение "свой" — это разные вещи. Поэтому ваш последний пример мне кажется неуместным.

Answer (score 0):

1. Заменить ИЛИ на И – и все станет прозрачно: **их** собственные интересы. К тому же, И и подходит лучше.
2. Производителем являются интересы?! "Волк пойман охотником" – здесь тоже производитель волк? Нет, не путайте подлежащее с производителем действия. Так что "свои" там очень даже подходит. Впрочем, и "их" тоже подходит.

Comment: 1) Не соглашусь, что подходит лучше. В нашем случае "клиент" и "заказчик" — это по сути одно лицо, только может по-разному называться. 2) "Волк пойман охотником", — здесь страдательный залог, конструкция другая. В нашем случае грамматически производителем действия являются именно "интересы", как бы нам ни казалось. К слову: "Клиента волнует конкурент своими ценами", — по-вашему, производитель действия — клиент, но не волнуют же его собственные цены. Так что грамматика в данном случае важнее семантики.

Answer (score 0):

Ввиду отсутствия подходящего правила предлагаю использовать правило о согласовании сказуемого с однородными подлежащими ([http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)). Оно отлично применимо для решения нашей задачи.

1. *Клиента или заказчика в первую очередь волнуют **его** собственные интересы.* (Единственное число, т. к. однородные члены относятся к одному грамматическому роду.)
2. *Клиента или клиентку в первую очередь волнуют **их** собственные интересы.* (Множественное число, т. к. однородные члены принадлежат к разному грамматическому роду.)

Возвратное местоимение **свой** использоваться не может, т. к. оно должно относиться к производителю соответствующего действия, а в предложении "грамматический" производитель действия — "интересы".

Comment: Мне идея понравилась (использовать множественное число, т. к. однородные члены принадлежат к разному грамматическому роду). Розеталь приводит пример: "Статья в целом или отрывок из нее представили бы интерес для читателей сборника". Однако мысль о том, что в данном случае местоимение *свой* использоваться не может, мне кажется ошибочной. Все зависит от контекста. О необязательности привязки к производителю действия см. в моем ответе.

Comment: *Возвратное местоимение **свой** использоваться не может* "У него свои причуды" - так нельзя? Ведь по-вашему, "производитель действия" здесь "причуды"? Другое дело, что обе ваши фразы построены неудачно (как это я пропустил): "волнуют свои интересы" -- это что? Так не говорят. "У клиентов свои интересы" - вот как будет правильно. А волновать могут не интересы, а, скажем, свои дела.

Comment: @Niemand "У него свои причуды" — здесь нет действия, а есть бытие (неполное предложение с опущенным сказуемым "есть"), поэтому "свой" звучит хорошо.

Comment: @Niemand "У него свои проблемы", "Его достали свои проблемы" — чувствуете разницу?

Comment: С @М_Г соглашусь: местоимение "свой" может не относиться к производителю действия — тогда, когда действия нет ("У него свои проблемы"). Но когда действие есть и есть производитель ("Его достали свои проблемы"), местоимение "свой" звучит коряво, согласитесь? А всё потому, что оно не "находит" правильный субъект, к которому может отнестись, а к дополнению относиться совсем "не хочет".